# Laravel Installer throwing error

Tags: laravel

I'm getting this error when calling the bash command
laravel new project

> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
>   php artisan clear-compiled

```
Warning: require(/Users/Dale/Desktop/Outstanding Projects/project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Dale/Desktop/Outstanding Projects/project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/Dale/Desktop/Outstanding Projects/project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/Dale/Desktop/Outstanding Projects/project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

Anyone come across this before.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you used [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install Laravel.

Laravel can't find your `autoload.php` file in `vendor` directory. Try `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`. Also check if `autoload.php` is in directory.

Path to `autoload.php` should be in `bootstrap/autoload.php` file, check if path is correct with your system.